# google_mobile_ads throws lots of Exceptions in Google Play Pre-launch report

Tags: flutter, admob, google-play-console, google-mobile-ads

I'm using google_mobile_ads ^2.0.1 in my Flutter app.

Just updated to 2.2.0, same problem.

On my test devices, everything is fine, ads load and are displayed as expected, nothing special in the logs.

However, when I upload an appbundle to the Google Play Console, the Pre-launch report throws lots of errors like:

```
Exception java.lang.LinkageError: Method void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.k03.onPostExecute(java.lang.Object) overrides final method in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/ads/g03; (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.k03' appears in /data/app/~~Z6C9g3Z86WigFhidsQn8Lw==/<appid>
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzflq.<init> (zzflq.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzflq.<clinit> (zzflq.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzflq.zzd (zzflq.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfku.zze (zzfku.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfko.zzf (zzfko.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfkd.zze (zzfkd.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzegj.zzd (zzegj.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcyp.zza (zzcyp.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcyp.zzn (zzcyp.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdej.zza (zzdej.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdif.run (zzdif.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcgx.execute (zzcgx.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcgz.execute (zzcgz.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdih.zzo (zzdih.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdek.zzn (zzdek.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzczc.zzW (zzczc.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxd.zzW (zzcxd.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzemu.zzb (zzemu.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzezb.zzb (zzezb.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfym.run (zzfym.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcgx.execute (zzcgx.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcgz.execute (zzcgz.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxf.zzz (zzfxf.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxf.zzy (zzfxf.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxf.zzt (zzfxf.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfzi.run (zzfzi.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfyc.execute (zzfyc.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxf.zzz (zzfxf.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxf.zzy (zzfxf.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxf.zzd (zzfxf.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxk.zzg (zzfxk.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxl.run (zzfxl.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfyc.execute (zzfyc.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcgz.execute (zzcgz.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfyz.execute (zzfyz.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxf.zzz (zzfxf.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxf.zzy (zzfxf.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxf.zzd (zzfxf.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfzg.zzd (zzfzg.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzchf.zzd (zzchf.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdut.zza (zzdut.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcmu.zzg (zzcmu.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcmu.onPageFinished (zzcmu.java)
  at mE0.a (mE0.java:425)
  at Da.handleMessage (Da.java:220)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7872)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

**My search on Google was no help. Anyone knows what this is about? Can I savely publish my update with these errors?**

Comment: Upgrading kotlin to `        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'`
gradle to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip`
and kotlin to `    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"`

solved it for me

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading kotlin to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'`

gradle to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip`

and kotlin to     `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"`

solved it for me

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/471